# Finding analytic expression with replacement rules

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, replacement

I have a function defined as

```
f[k_]:= Maximize[{(x^2/(1+x^2))((1-x^(2k))/(1+x^(2k+1)))^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

I would like to find an analytic form of $f$ as a function of $k$.

Differentiating the argument of the Maximize in $f$ with respect to $x$, I obtain the condition:

```
1+x^(3+4k) - x^(2k)(1+x)(x^2(1+2k)- x + (1+2k)) == 0
```

Is there a way I can write a replacement rule in Mathematica to substitute the above condition on $x$, and get $f$ as a function of $k$ alone?

Comment: **1.** Curly braces have a specific meaning in Mathematica, indicating lists, so you should not write `x^{2 k}`, but instead `x^(2 k)`. Similarly for the `x^{2 k + 1}` which should be `x^(2 k + 1)`. **2.** When you say that you differentiated $f$, you really meant that you differentiated the argument of the `Maximize` in $f$. **3.** The resulting equation has multiple exponents containing k and does not look like it would have a symbolic solution. See `FullSimplify[ D[(x^2/(1 + x^2)) ((1 - x^(2 k))/(1 + x^(2 k + 1)))^2, k] == 0]`.

Comment: Thanks, edited as per your comment.